# Calibrating g2++ in negative interest rate environment

Tags: short-rate, modelling

I am working on a g2++ model in a dualcurve setup for both Euribor and EONIA. I have the model built, but have some issues in calibrating it - I get a perfect fit with a Nelder-Mead algorithm, but it seems like it is shifted downwards compared to the ZC curve (for both of the g2++ models).

Can anybody help me to as how to calibrate the G2++? I am trying currently with ATM Swaptions and R (ESG2 package, quantlib does not seem able to handle negative rates unfortunately), but willing to try other programs as well if it can help me solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> quantlib does not seem able to handle negative rates

The [slides](https://www.quantlib.org/slides/qlum15/caspers1.pdf) by Peter Caspers discuss 'QL_NEGATIVE_RATES" and related topics in a very accessible style.